# Is there a way to create an mxd from the command line?

Tags: arcmap, batch, mxd, command-line

Is there a way to run ArcMap in a batch script to create a basic mxd containing specified layers? Something like:

> "Path to ArcMap exe" -create "Path to new mxd" -include "layers to add"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I know.

However, you can copy a blank mxd then modify it using arcpy.mapping in Python (command lines from the python windows might not be exactly what you expect, but you can create a small script in Python that you launch within a single command line if you prefer).

```
import arcpy.mapping    
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("path_to_mxd_template")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
lyrFile = arcpy.mapping.Layer("path_to_layer.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, lyrFile)
mxd.save(new_name)
```